org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server
My Company has a solr cloud installation. The server throws IO Exception while an external application tries to talk to the server for indexing. Following is the error message
SolrServerException occure while indexing solr for transactionId: 20059192046","exception":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at:
http://someip:8993/solr\n\tat
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:695)\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266)\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214)
